# How to input a number which will result in searching a list then a dictionary for confirmation

Tags: python, dictionary

So I keep getting the error "TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable" for my code. What I want to do is have a number as an input and then have a function that searches first a list, then a dictionary for that number. If that number is in the dictionary, then return some info. I think I know why the error message pops up, but I am asking for an alternative to do what I want.

```
item1 = {
    "name": "Item 1",
    "code": 1001,
}

item2 = {
    "name": "Item 2",
    "code": 1002,
}

item3 = {
    "name": "Item 3",
    "code": 1003,
}

produce = [item1, item2, item3]

def produce_info_code(x):
    print
    produce_name = input("Enter Produce code [eg. 1234]: ")
    if produce_name["code"] in x:
        return "Name: %s" % produce_name["name"], "Code: %s" % produce_name["code]

print produce_info_code(produce)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you posted your entire code because according to this, there is no way you can get the above error. Anyway, the actual problem is, the returned value from `input()` is a `str` type which is not subscriptable.

```
def produce_info_code(x):
    produce_name = int(input("Enter Produce code [eg. 1234]: "))
    for dct in x:
        if produce_name == dct.get("code")
            return "Name: %s" % dct["name"], "Code: %d" % produce_name
    return None
```

Comment: I imported the code and had to delete the str() in str(dct["code"]) and it worked

Comment: Updated my code. However, using `dct.get` is much safer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Generator Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) like following:

```
def produce_info_code(x):
    produce_name = int(input("Enter Produce code [eg. 1234]: "))
    return next((("Name: %s, Code: %d" % (item["name"],produce_name)) for item in produce if item["code"] == produce_name),None)
```